# how to fetch bill report for a particular IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-billing

I have an root aws account and also created one IAM users.  The IAM user have full permission for EC2 service.  He/She create a Instance(virtual machine - t2.nano) from his IAM account.

I am check my bill from root account.  I am seeing as combined usage of root user and IAM user.  Is it possible to separate the billing usage for IAM user alone?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to track the billing usage for a IAM user unless you create a (cost allocation) tag for that user and track it in billing reports. Even then, you can track only the compute costs (instance cost) not the costs associated with storage, data transfer etc.,

Comment: thanks, helloV.  I started thinking about linked accounts in the mean time.  Would that be helpful?